# TypeError 'Module' object is not callable (SymPy)

Tags: python, sympy

As the Topic says, module is not callable and I don't really understand why. Its (probably) not the same problem from the similar post, at least I don't know what should I import. I am using SymPy.

And this is a full error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Marek\Desktop\Bartłomiej\SymPy\PrimeTest.py", line 16, in <module>
        if isinstance(evalf((n/p).subs(x, 1)), int):
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Full code:

```
from sympy import *
import math 
import sys
import mpmath
sys.modules['sympy.mpmath'] = mpmath

x, y = symbols(' x y ')

#p = sympfy(input(Check this: ))
p = 100

n = expand(((x-1)**p - (x**p - 1)))

print(n) 

if isinstance(evalf((n/p).subs(x, 1)), int):
    print("This number is a prime!")
else:
    print("It is not a prime")
```

I am trying to make a test for a prime number. (x-1)^p - (x^p - 1), if this is dividable by p and p != 1 then its a prime. My code is not quality because I am changing x to 1 , but I wanna check if it would work..

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: whre is `if isinstance(evalf((n/p).subs(x, 1)), int):`?

Comment: This looks dangerous `from sympy import *`. The error message shown means you called something like a function that was actually a Python module. In your traceback the only code shown is calling `evalf`. So what is `evalf` in this case?

Comment: Also [according to the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/install.html#mpmath) in order to use this `mpmath` hack with sympy you must do it *before* you import sympy, which makes sense to me.

Comment: @Iguananaut, should it look like this?: import sys import mpmath sys.modules['sympy.mpmath'] = mpmath from sympy import * import math

Comment: Yes, probably should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're using evalf() incorrectly.

From what I've seen, it should be `((n/p).subs(x, 1)).evalf()`

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html

It might be something else, but give it a try.

Comment: I think it works, codewise its wrong but this problem on my side.